# how to make requests to pages that load javascript

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to make requests to these two pages:

url1= https://antonioli.eu/it/IT/men/t/categories/shoes/sneakers

url2= https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/t/seasons/ss2019

I state that I **do not want to use Selenium**.

I tried with library **requests** (also sessions), **scrapy with splash**, **HTMLSession** from requests_html (trying to render html), **dryscrape** and **urllib.request**, but none of these things found a solution.

Is there another way to get the page result?

for each of these "request", I got this common response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=/ciez2a">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
function md5cycle(e,t)

....
....
....

    (new Fingerprint2).get(function(e,t){
      salt="768539096";
      document.cookie="ipp_sign="+e+"_"+salt+"_"+md5(e+salt)+"; expires=Tue, 31 Dec 2030 23:59:59 GMT; path=/;";
      ipp.setCookie();
      location.href="https://www.off---white.com/en/IT/men/t/seasons/ss2019?";
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that these pages use cookies for dispatching response, but I don't know how to generate fake cookies.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Well, you can't, can you? Not from a browser. You will be blocked by CORS policy, unless these sites explicitely allow cross-domain requests

Comment: *I do not want to use Selenium* - that is great, then you just have to write either selenium or a browser yourself.

Comment: We also don't know what you want from the pages.

Comment: What did you get when using Splash?

Comment: you could do one of the following 1) see if you can get the data through XHR; 2) sometimes the data is in the html source under the `<script>` tags; or 3) try [Requests-HTML](https://html.python-requests.org/) which has javascript support, but I haven't used it before

Comment: @QHarr I need to read products from these websites.

Comment: @Gallaecio I have the same response of a simple requests.

Comment: @chitown88 I just tried with Requests-HTML but do not works, how can I get data with XHR?

Comment: @M.T. it's definite, but you can check by opening the dev tools in the browser